# self-tracking-entities and lazy loading

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, self-tracking-entities

Is there a way to use lazy loading and self-tracking-entities while the context is open?

Will there be any issues and what do I have to consider?

Thanks a lot for your aswer in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lazy loading is not supported with STEs at all because lazy loading demands dynamic proxy created over entity but STEs are not proxied by design - [check additional notes in summary](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/22/feature-ctp-walkthrough-self-tracking-entities-for-the-entity-framework.aspx) or [MSDN question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/6133d1a8-5952-4168-bcb6-756202341238).